# Query to select from all tables that have the same value in the same column

Tags: db2

Database is called 'school'. 'school' has tables with 'classroom_names' i.e 'room1' as a table, 'room2' as another table, etc. and each 'classroom_names' has a 'student_name' column.

I want to select all 'classroom_names' where it has a 'student_name' called 'John'.

So far I can only select all 'classroom_names' from the database like his:

```
  select * from syscat.tables
```

Comment: This is a very poor database design and there really is no way way to do it easy.

Comment: The problem is that your table names (which is meta data) contain relational date.  I would expect a single table with the relationship between the room (room name or ID) and the student (student name or ID) as two columns to exist.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following.  (Which tries to fix some of the problems with your design)

Create the following View

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SCHOOL.STUDENT_LIST AS
    SELECT 'Room1' as CLASSROOM, student_name FROM SCHOOL.Room1
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Room2' as CLASSROOM, student_name FROM SCHOOL.Room2
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Room3' as CLASSROOM, student_name FROM SCHOOL.Room3
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Room4' as CLASSROOM, student_name FROM SCHOOL.Room4
      UNION ALL
     -- etc
    SELECT 'RoomN' as CLASSROOM, student_name FROM SCHOOL.RoomN
```

Now you can say

```
 SELECT CLASSROOM FROM STUDENT_LIST WHERE student_name = 'John'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can built a dynamic query from the DB2 catalog

```
db2 "select 'select ' || trim(tabname) || ' classroom, student_name from '
 || tabname || ' where student_name = ''John'';'
from syscat.tables
where tabname like 'room%'" | db2 +p -tv
```

The last part (db2 +p -tv) allows to execute the output. If it does not work (buffer size), just remove this, and copy paste the output.